# Extracting LLVM IR Identifiers

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have an instruction visitor implemented that inspects `FCmpInst`. In my IR, I have a couple lines generated from clang on a c++ file:

```
%2 = load float, float* %x, align 4
%3 = fcmp ogt float %2, 1.0000e+00
```

Calling `getOperand(0)` during the `FCmpInst` visit returns the `load` instruction above. Then, if I call `getPointerOperand()` on the `load` instruction, it points back to the `alloca` instruction that first sets aside `%x`. I do not want the pointer - instead, I want the identifier name "%x". How do we extract these names from the IR? I see that calling `dump()` on any instruction shows the identifier, but I have not found an API call that could pull out the identifier itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getName` method](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html#ad452febc1ac0b394876e640ec03ffa38) on `Value`.

Note that not every value is named -- in particular, you won't be able to retrieve names like `%1`, `%2`, etc. as those are generated on the fly while the IR is being written out.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the `getName` method but, as you say, it returns empty strings. When you call `dump()` on Values, the information is all there! So what data structure maintains the entire string? I would be happy take take that and parse out the `%` symbols. Keep in mind, I have the IR file and I am sending it into a `ModulePass`.

Comment: Are you calling getName on the `load` instruction or the `alloca` instruction?

Comment: Yes I am, but most instructions have no name. I decided that my pass will run through the entire list of instructions and assign names myself before doing any more analysis on the code. I did see [this operation](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/AsmWriter_8cpp_source.html#l02688) in the `AsmWriter` class that shows the identifiers being labelled during the raw_ostream calls. That at least answers my questions about "where" identifiers are stored: they are generated on the fly by the printing process.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing. I needed to detect global identifiers.

`isa<GlobalValue>(mem_address)` did it for me.